# PHPMailer now wotking wiht Helm Window Hosting

Tags: php, phpmailer

When i am trying to send email using my email id and password.... i got an error like this

> SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP bq1sm22317669obb.20 -
>   gsmtp SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250 mx.google.com at your service SMTP ->
>   ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via
>   your web browser and then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534
>   5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 bq1sm22317669obb.20 - gsmtp SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250 2.1.5 Flushed
>   bq1sm22317669obb.20 - gsmtp SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 530-5.5.1
>   Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1
>   http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257
>   bq1sm22317669obb.20 - gsmtp SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from
>   server: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1
>   http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257
>   bq1sm22317669obb.20 - gsmtp The following From address failed:
>   myemailaddress@gmail.com Mailer Error: The following From address
>   failed: myemailaddress@gmail.com

here code of smtp phpmailer :

```
$mail             = new PHPMailer();
                        $body             = eregi_replace('[\]','',$body);

                        $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
                      //  $mail->Host       = "mail.shreejicera.com"; // SMTP server
                        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                                                   // 1 = errors and messages
                                                                   // 2 = messages only
                        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
                        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
                        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
                        $mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
                        $mail->Username   = "myemailaddress@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
                        $mail->Password   = "password";            // GMAIL password

                        $mail->SetFrom('myemailaddress@gmail.com', 'mysite.com');

                        $mail->AddReplyTo("myemailaddress@gmail.com","mysite.com");

                        $mail->Subject    = $subject;

                        $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

                        $mail->MsgHTML($body);

                        if(is_array($to))
                        {
                            $address=$to[0];
                            $name=$to[1];
                        }else
                        {
                            $address = $to;
                            $name="";
                        }
                        $mail->AddAddress($address, $name);


                        if(!$mail->Send()) {
                          echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                          return false;  
                        } else {
                          return true;
                        }
```

Please give me suggestion where am i wrong....

Comment: Well, to state the obvious: "Password not accepted from server. Please log in via your web browser and then try again". So, get over to gmail and login with those credentials and see if it works.

Comment: If that doesn't work: Gmail SMTP port (TLS): 587

Comment: thanks with 2 step verification it is cause error